# Holomorphic functions with removable singularities are actually holomorphic on the whole domain

Tags: complex-analysis

This is from Stein and Shakarchi's text on complex analysis:
[image]

So to be strictly correct $f(z)/z$ is actually not defined at the origin, but when we say it is holomorphic on the disk because the origin is a removable singularity, we are actually just identifying it with its extension with the singularity removed. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, MMP is applied to the unique extension of $\frac {f(z)} z$.

Comment: MMP? Is there an ISO standard for such abbreviations?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez OP already talked about maxumum modulus principle, so I thought he would  know the expansion of MMP. Actually, this abbreviation is used in several books.